# How may i use different urls in twisted autobahn?

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, autobahn

I need something like in tornado. Each Websocket Handler for each url. For example, I have different urls: ws://localhost/url1, ws://localhost/url2 and i need separate handler for each of them. Is it possible? I tried to set url in WebSocketServerFactory but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have it either by mapping the requested URL by overriding `WebSocketServerProtocol.onConnect` or by setting up a Twisted Web resource tree that has specific handlers.

Please see https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/multiproto for complete examples of both approaches.

Comment: Could we get a updated URL? Would like to do this as well. Cheers